# Grep for prior match

Tags: kubernetes, grep

It's best to explain with an example what I want to achieve.

I have this kubectl output:

```
app-bf7c5cdfb-x8thq   3/3     Running   0          2h
app-bf7c5cdfb-xc9nf   3/3     Running   0          2h
app-bf7c5cdfb-xwlzh   2/3     Running   0          1h
app-bf7c5cdfb-xxt46   3/3     Running   0          2h
app-bf7c5cdfb-z9s2t   2/3     Running   0          7m
app-bf7c5cdfb-zmpzs   3/3     Running   0          2h
app-bf7c5cdfb-ztfx5   3/3     Running   0          2h
```

I want to grep for each line, where the ready pods are not equal to the total pods resulting in:

```
app-bf7c5cdfb-xwlzh   2/3     Running   0          1h
app-bf7c5cdfb-z9s2t   2/3     Running   0          7m
```

Is there a simple way to do that? My approach is writing a function like this:

```
function kubeNotReady {
    unset tmp
    while :
    do 
        read line
        [[ $line == "" ]] && tmp="${tmp:0:$((${#tmp}-1))}" && break

        total=`echo "$line" | sed -E "s|.*[[:digit:]]*/([[:digit:]]*).*|\1|"`
        match=`echo "$line" | grep -v "$total/$total"`
        if [ "${#match}" -gt "0" ]; then
            tmp="$tmp$match"$'\n'
        fi
    done
    echo "$tmp"
}
```

```
kubectl get po | kubeNotReady
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a grep which is something like what you want.

`echo "4/5" | grep -vE "^(.+)/\1$"`

That handles just the fraction. To make it handle your provided example simply filter out everything apart from the 2nd word before passing it to the grep I provided.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick I think I tried that before, but somehow I must have done smth. wrong.
```
kubectl get pod  | grep -vE "(\d+)/\1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If `AWK` is your option, please try the following:

```
awk '{split($2, a, "/"); if (a[1] != a[2]) print}' out.txt
```

As an alternative, you can say with `bash` as:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ [[:blank:]]([[:digit:]]+)/([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]] ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} != ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} )) && echo "$line"
done < out.txt
```

Hope this helps.